# Counting calendar days in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I've got a task to calculate how many days are left until a certain deadline expires.
For example: I have a 10 business days deadline starting today (let's assume it's a Monday). I need to calculate how many calendar days remain until that deadline expires. Which means I need to see how many weekends fall into this time period and add them to the "remaining days" result (which in our concrete example should be 12 days since only one weekend will fall in this timeframe).

How do I do that on iOS?

Let me know if you need more clarification

Comment: i am not getting your problem .please give some info .use example and explain it

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi Ok, imagine that you have a certain task to do within a 10 business days deadline (business days: Monday - Friday). You have to calculate how many days are left until you reach that deadline. So in essence, the result will be: 10 days + all weekend days that will appear in the following days. For example if we would have been calculating starting from a Monday then the number of days left would be 12 days (as we would encounter only 2 weekend days in this period)

Comment: And the question is how to perform these calculations programmatically on iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int numberOfDays=30;

NSDate *startDate=[NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *offset = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *dates = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:startDate];
NSMutableArray *weekends = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableArray *businessDays = [NSMutableArray new];

if (![self isDateWeekend:startDate]) {
    [businessDays addObject:startDate];
}

for (int i = 1; i < numberOfDays; i++) {
    [offset setDay:i];
    NSDate *nextDay = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:offset toDate:startDate options:0];
    [dates addObject:nextDay];
    [businessDays addObject:nextDay];
    if ([self isDateWeekend:nextDay]) {
        [weekends addObject:nextDay];
        [businessDays removeObject:nextDay];
    }
}

NSLog(@"All Days%@",dates);
NSLog(@"All Weekends%@",weekends);
NSLog(@"Business Days%@",businessDays);
```

The weekend function has been borrowed from an other SO answer as it was neater,

```
- (BOOL) isDateWeekend:(NSDate*)date
{
    NSRange weekdayRange = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] maximumRangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitWeekday];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
    NSUInteger weekdayOfDate = [components weekday];
    if (weekdayOfDate == weekdayRange.location || weekdayOfDate == weekdayRange.length) {
            //the date falls somewhere on the first or last days of the week
            return YES;
        }
        else
            return NO;
 }
```

This can be extended to get all days,weekends and business days within a date range.

Comment: alright so the accepted answer turned out to be flawed. I'm looking to an alternative solution. I like how you started your answer, but would you know how to take a time interval and sift through each date to see if it's a weekend day or not? For example: let's say I have a start date and end date, I need to go through all the dates in between to see if it's a weekend day or not.

Comment: @SergeyCatraniuc i have edited my answer with a modified solution, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: thanks, I've found the best solution by combining your answer and a couple of other solutions on SO. But yours was the closest one to what I needed in the big picture

Comment: @SergeyCatraniuc glad i could be of help.

Answer (score 0):

do some calculation here .
and try like this .

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents     = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:today];

//calcuate number of days to substract from today
NSDateComponents *componentsToSubtract  = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[componentsToSubtract setDay: (0 - ((dayofweek + 5) % 7))];
[componentsToSubtract setHour: 0 - [weekdayComponents hour]];
[componentsToSubtract setMinute: 0 - [weekdayComponents minute]];
[componentsToSubtract setSecond: 0 - [weekdayComponents second]];

//Create date for first day in week
NSDate *beginningOfWeek = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:componentsToSubtract toDate:today options:0];


NSDateComponents *componentsToAdd = [gregorian components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:beginningOfWeek];
[componentsToAdd setDay:6];

NSDate *endOfWeek = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:componentsToAdd toDate:beginningOfWeek options:0]
```

Comment: could you please take a look at my comment above and see if it clarifies what I need and if your answer is still valid

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear| NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
int weekDay = components.weekday;
int numberOfweeks = numberOfDays/5;
int weekDayDiff = 7 - weekDay;
if (weekDayDiff >= 5 && numberOfDays%5 == 0) {
    numberOfweeks --;
}
numberOfDays += numberOfweeks * 2;
```

Comment: This returns 14 days which is incorrect, OP has explained the requirement in a comment to his question.

Comment: @Preson actually it's correct, because it's calculating starting today (which is a Friday) in that case there are 4 weekend days that fall under the 10 business days deadline. So 14 is correct.

Comment: I think there is some tweaking to do. But this works for now. So I'll mark it as accepted unless someone proves it wrong :)

Comment: @Preson yes, this seams to be it, but thanks for taking the time and answering :)

Comment: @Akhilrajtr For some reason this fails when the number of business days can't be divided by 5. So for example when I give it 13 business days, and the starting date is a Monday, it gives me the result of 15 days left, when it should be 17

Comment: @Akhilrajtr thanks for updating, although it did fix it and now it calculates correctly, the answer isn't really flexible as Person's answer (doesn't give me direct access to business and weekend days, which is what I'll need in my future development). However it's a great alternative if the only thing you need is to get the remaining days.